# How to trim UIIMageView in places that collide with other views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uikit

I have a line that goes through some views and should have spaces in places that collide between them. How can I do that? Line is a UIIMageView and the whole screen is a UIView class.

Of course, I can make 4 image views and place them accordingly, but I feel like there is a way to make it prettier.

More info on screenshot how it should be, thank you.

[image]

Comment: For something as simple as a line, why don't you just use a custom view that draws a line? That way you just need four instances of this view, each of which is the right width and therefore draws the right length of line. Your use of UIImageView and a UIImage seems like total overkill.

Comment: seems a bit hard for me now to understand how to draw a line that can skip places that collide with other views

Comment: @eeeyyeeezz - there are many different ways to do this, but we need more detail. Are your "line segments" fixed-widths? Or, should they be a percentage of the view width? In your image, are the "hand, arc and clock" all one image, that you are sliding, and the "line gap" needs to change as you more that image?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for long-time usage, without image:
[StackView: horizontal and fill with subView self-constrained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnjt5.png).

I use `InterfaceBuilder` only it is hard to describe step by step so I just expand all `subViews` and note the size of views by changing its name on IB (InterfaceBuilder), then make a screenshot to attach it here.

`StackView` is one of great `View Container` that reduces your time to do layouts for views with constraints or even without constraints. It allows you can swap position of subviews easily without changing the layout setting or need to perform layouts again.

Hope that you can solve your problem.

Comment: Interesting solution, will try thanks! 

But btw i use only code so guess it will take time :)